# Hibernate OneToMany mapping for same table

Tags: hibernate-mapping

I have a student table where one student can have many friends. Friend is also a student.
So I have added one more table Friends with three columns id, studentid, friendid where studentid and friendid are foreignkeys for id in student table. Now how do I do OneToMany maping in Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a OneToMany but a ManyToMany that you need to use here!
A Student can have many Friends and he can be the Friend of many Students.

```
public class Student {

   private List<Student> friends;

}
```

And the HBM mapping :

```
<set name="friends" table="FRIENDSHIP">
   <key column="studentId"/>
   <many-to-many column="friendId" class="Student"/>
</set>
```